# wait for a promise inside a directive before rendering

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('rowe.desktop').directive('bottomBar', function ($translate, sessionService) {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'modules/desktop/shared/directives/views/_bottomBar.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope) {
      var nowDate = new Date();
     $translate('COPYRIGHT').then((translation)=>{
       scope.copyright = translation;
     })
    }
  };
})
```

the translation service acutally returns a promise and I need to wait for that promise to get resolved before the rendering is performed. Any suggestions?

Comment: `<div ng-if="copyright">...</div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use ngIf on the root element of the template to make prevent the root element from rendering unless the ngIf condition is true.

If your template looks as follows:

```
<div>This is the template of the directive</div>
```

you can add an ngIf that is false initially, therefore not rendering the div.

```
<div ng-if="allowRendering">This is the template of the directive</div>
```

in your directive you set `allowRendering` to true whenever you feel like the template should be rendered.

I have created an example in JSFiddle: [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/24/)